# Installing Rosetta 2 on this system is not supported

Tags: macos, homebrew

I use the MacBook with 2,3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
And when I type
`arch -x86_64 brew install scriptcs` 
It occurs `Cannot install on Intel processor in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!` 
so how can I fix it????

Answer (score 0):

> Dual-Core Intel Core i5

If your MacBook has an Intel processor, then you don’t need Rosetta.